# Variable not passing into stored procedure

Tags: php, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I'm an absolute beginner at php and okay with sql. So, due apologies for the messy coding.

I'm currently trying to pass a variable which contains the value '0004', data type VARCHAR(4), into a stored procedure which I created on mysql. Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head><title> AmountDue </title><head>
<body>

<h1> Amount Due </h1>


<?php
$guestid = "0004";
$mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'username', 'pass', 'schemaname');



$rs = $mysqli->query( 'CALL FindRoomCost('.$guestid.', @roomCost);');
$rs = $mysqli->query( 'CALL FindFoodCost('.$guestid.', @foodCost);');
$rs = $mysqli->query( 'CALL FindSpaCost('.$guestid.', @spaCost);');
$rs = $mysqli->query( 'SELECT gu.guest_id, bi.invoice_no, gu.first_name,
                       gu.last_name, @roomCost + @foodCost + @spaCost AS
                       TotalCost FROM guest gu, bill bi
                       WHERE gu.guest_id = bi.guest_no
                       AND gu.guest_id = '.$guestid.';' );      

print "<table border=1>";
print "<TR><TH>GuestID</TH><TH>InvoiceNumber</TH><TH>FirstName</TH<TH>LastName</TH><TH>TotalCost</TH></TR>";


while ($r2 = mysqli_fetch_row($rs)) {
  print "<tr>"; 
  for ($k=0; $k<count($r2); $k++){  
    print "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($r2[$k]) . "</td>"; 
  } 
  print "</tr>";    
}
print "</table>";
print "<HR width=85%>";
?>
```

The code successfully displays the guest name, ID, invoice number that is linked to the requested guestid. However, it does not call the stored procedures that I want. Though if I manually input '0004', instead of $guestid, in the procedure's parameters, the stored procedures will successfully run and give me the TotalCost which is the result I want. I know there's nothing wrong with my stored procedures but I'll just post it just in case. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

FindRoomCost

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `FindRoomCost`
(
IN guestTag VARCHAR(4),
OUT roomCost INT
)
BEGIN

SELECT
(DATEDIFF(res.check_out_date, res.check_in_date))*(count(DISTINCT(ro.room_id)) * (ro.room_rate))
INTO roomCost 
FROM room ro, reservation res
WHERE ro.guest_number = res.guest_id
AND ro.guest_number = guestTag;

END
```

FindFoodCost

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `FindFoodCost`
(
IN guestTag VARCHAR(4),
OUT foodCost INT
)
BEGIN

SELECT CASE
WHEN nrc.invoice_no IN (bi.invoice_no)
    THEN SUM(DISTINCT(nrc.quantity * sm.menu_price))
    ELSE 0
END
INTO foodCost
FROM bill bi, non_room_charge nrc, set_menu sm
WHERE bi.invoice_no = nrc.invoice_no
AND nrc.menu_no = sm.menu_id
AND bi.guest_no = guestTag;

END
```

FindSpaCost

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `FindSpaCost`
(
IN guestTag VARCHAR(4),
OUT spaCost INT
)
BEGIN

SELECT CASE
WHEN nrc.invoice_no IN (bi.invoice_no)
    THEN SUM(DISTINCT(nrc.quantity * sp.spa_price))
    ELSE 0
END
INTO spaCost
FROM bill bi, non_room_charge nrc, spa_package sp
WHERE bi.invoice_no = nrc.invoice_no
AND nrc.spa_no = sp.spa_id
AND bi.guest_no = guestTag;

END
```

Answer (score 1):

**Remove the periods.**

```
$rs = $mysqli->query( 'CALL FindRoomCost('.$guestid.', @roomCost);');
```

**CHANGE TO:**

```
$rs = $mysqli->query( 'CALL FindRoomCost('$guestid', @roomCost);');
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It instead gives me a Parse Error: Syntax Error.

Comment: try this.  $rs = $mysqli->query( 'CALL FindRoomCost("'.$guestid.'", @roomCost);');

Comment: Solved. I just used a $mysqli->prepare, bind_param and execute for the Stored Procedures. Thanks anyway!